# Azure virtual machines in the same network can't see each other

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I created a virtual network in Azure and added few VMs in it.
My expectation was to Ping/Access each machine from the other machine in the same network. However, machines don't seem to recognize each other.
[image: Virtual Network and the machines in them]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <NetworkConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2011/07/NetworkConfiguration" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<VirtualNetworkConfiguration>

<Dns/>


-<VirtualNetworkSites>


-<VirtualNetworkSite Location="East US" name="AshishGupta">


-<AddressSpace>

<AddressPrefix>172.16.0.0/12</AddressPrefix>

</AddressSpace>


-<Subnets>


-<Subnet name="Subnet-1">

<AddressPrefix>172.16.0.0/15</AddressPrefix>

</Subnet>

</Subnets>

</VirtualNetworkSite>

</VirtualNetworkSites>

</VirtualNetworkConfiguration>

</NetworkConfiguration>
```

Comment: You should post this to ServerFault, since it's network-related and not programming-related.

Answer (score 3):

If by "don't seem to recognize each other" you mean you can't send and receive ICMP pings that's because ICMP is disabled on Azure VMs.

Try opening a TCP socket on the desired port running the service to which you want to verify connectivity instead:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient "192.168.10.10", 8043


Client              : System.Net.Sockets.Socket
Available           : 0
Connected           : True
ExclusiveAddressUse : False
ReceiveBufferSize   : 65536
SendBufferSize      : 65536
ReceiveTimeout      : 0
SendTimeout         : 0
LingerState         : System.Net.Sockets.LingerOption

NoDelay             : False
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to Azure, but check your firewall settings.  If you can't even ping the VM and you are sure it's up, make sure ICMP ECHO is not blocked by your firewall.

Comment: I am able to remote into the VMs from my desktop. Can't ping VMs from one another.

Comment: Being able to RDP into the VM isn't the same as being able to ping it.

Comment: ICMP is disabled in Azure, so ping isn't a good troubleshooting tool.