# VMs unable to reach each-other in Azure

Tags: networking, azure

---

First off, I found a similar issue [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/674112/azure-virtual-machines-in-the-same-network-cant-see-each-other), but it's 5 years old and I don't see any solution there + Azure has changed a lot since then, I'm sure.

### My test lab:

VMs: 1 Windows, 1 Linux.

NICs: Windows has one (Internal). IP forwarding is Disabled, Linux has two (Internal and Public). IP forwarding Enabled on both.

Subnets: One for Internal NICs, one for Public. Both VMs are on the Internal subnet, Linux's PIP interface is also on the Public subnet.

NSGs: I have one NSG spanning both subnets. A very generic one. Default rules + allow all incoming RDP/SSH.

Route Tables: I have one Route Table per subnet. (This part is actually the most confusing for me in Azure context)

I'm terrible at explaining stuff, so I made some diagrams as well, to make matters more confusing:
[current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S89E6.png), [expected end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM7QA.png).

### The Problem

I tested using Linux VM as a router for a Windows instance at my home lab and it worked (Hyper-V), so I'm expecting the same result from Azure.

But right now, the biggest problem is that although the VMs are in the same subnet, they can't reach each-other. RDP (3389) is listening on Windows and SSH (22) is listening on Linux.
When I try to `nmap -sT 10.0.2.5 -p 3389 -Pn` on Linux side, it tells me that the connection is filtered (should be open). And when I run `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 10.0.2.254 -Port 22` on Windows side, the TCP check fails.

Windows Firewall allows the whole "Remote Desktop" Firewall Group on all Firewall Profiles. Tried also disabling the Firewall, but it didn't matter.

Additionally, maybe someone finds this bit of information useful: When I add a NIC to WindowsVM, which has PIP and is in external/public subnet, the VMs are able to contact each-other. But the Windows VM should NOT have public interface in this instance.

### Get-Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it working!**

*Changes as per current setup diagram link listed in original post.*

Removed Route Table from testPublicSN

Removed Routes from testIntRT and added the following route:

```
0.0.0.0/0 Virtual Appliance 10.0.2.254
```

Also, disabled Virtual network gateway propagation on testIntRT.

Removed NSG from Subnets and moved it to Public NIC.

Enabled IP forwarding on WindowsVM's NIC.